# How to configure git to ignore spaces in detecting conflicts during a merge?

Tags: git

A lot of the conflicts git detects are lines or spaces, or coding style changes.
Is there a way to ignore such differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a question better suited for stackoverflow.

[Is it possible for git merge to ignore line ending differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences)

[Git merge and fixing mixed spaces and tabs with two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256769/git-merge-and-fixing-mixed-spaces-and-tabs-with-two-branches)

My preference is to include an indent template and running that before check-in.